# Calculation Columns in DataGridView bounded to an object

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

My UI consist of a datagridview (`AutoCreateColumns= false`) bound to a list of my business objects. Let's assume my Object contains 2 columns - Price and Quantity - and I'd want to add a new column in my grid - Total - which value will be calculated - Price*Quantity, **BUT** with no modification of my Business object.

Is it possible?

Comment: If You mean if it's possible to edit data through grid - No.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

You can add unbound columns to a grid programmatically, and you populate the column’s cells either using events.

There are two primary ways to populate the contents of unbound columns: handling the **RowsAdded** event or handling the **CellFormatting** event. If the grid is editable **CellValueChanged** also needs to be handled. The CellFormatting event can also be used to transform values as they are presented in a cell to something different than the value that is actually stored in the data that sits behind the grid.

**Code Sample -**

```
private void OnCellFormatting(object sender,
   DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.ColumnIndex == grid.Columns["Unbound"].Index)
    {
       e.FormattingApplied = true;
       DataGridViewRow row = grid.Rows[e.RowIndex];
       e.Value = string.Format("{0} : {1}",
          row.Cells["SomeColumn1"].Value,
          row.Cells["SomeColumn2"].Value);
    }
}

private void OnRowsAdded(object sender,
   DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{

   for (int i = 0; i < e.RowCount; i++)
   {
      DataGridViewRow row = grid.Rows[e.RowIndex + i];
      row.Cells["Unbound"].Value = string.Format("{0} : {1}",
         row.Cells["SomeColumn1"].Value,
         row.Cells["SomeColumn2"].Value);
    }
}
```

More in detail - http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=446453&seqNum=5

Comment: Thanks, this approach seems very close to what I need. Even data refresh works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: A little mention - for Value field of DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs parameter should be assigned only **string** values

Comment: ok.. hmm.. is the cell blank when its something else? Does it not show the toString() representation of the object?

Comment: No, just enough to take the string representation of what it's need to be show.

Answer (score 0):

No, not without editing your object.